# Sine of number using Taylor Series java

Tags: java, algorithm

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TaylorSeries{

public static int factorial(int num){
    if(num == 0) return 1;
    return num * factorial(num -1);
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the number:");

    int num = scanner.nextInt();
    boolean op_checker = true;

    int denom = 0;
    double numrad = num * (2 * Math.PI/360);
    double sum = 0;

    for(int counter = 0; counter < 4; counter++){
        denom = counter * 2 + 1;
        if(op_checker)
                sum += Math.pow(numrad,(double)denom)/factorial(denom);
        else    sum -= Math.pow(numrad,(double)denom)/factorial(denom); 

        op_checker = op_checker ? false : true;   
        System.out.println(sum);
    }  

    System.out.printf("%.4f",sum); 
}

}
```

The problem is that the values I get are incorrect when the number is very close to 90 and beyond. Can anyone help me understand what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

This

```
      sum += sum + Math.pow(...
 else sum -= sum + Math.pow(...
```

should be

```
      sum += Math.pow(...
 else sum -= Math.pow(...
```

Comment: Alright thanks. I've updated the question. I'd appreciate your answer to that.

Answer (score 0):

```
   sum += sum + Math.pow(numrad,(double)denom)/factorial(denom);
```

should be

```
sum = sum + Math.pow(numrad,(double)denom)/factorial(denom);
or 
sum +=  Math.pow(numrad,(double)denom)/factorial(denom);
```

Note that your approach is rather ineffective. To get next series term, you can multiply the last one with `(x*x)/((2*i)(2*i+1))`

Series convergence is slow for big argument values - that is why you can see large errors. You have to get more terms (extensive way) or reduce argument to small range (recommended).

Another possible error reason - your `factorial` function won't work for large `denom` due to integer overflow. You can use double as it's result or apply more robust algorithm that I described above.

Comment: Oh! yeah thanks. I don't know why I always make that mistake. Thanks.

Comment: Alright thanks. I've updated the question. Can you help me provide an answer to that?

Comment: Ok! Thanks so much for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

```
package algorithms;

public class TaylorSeries {

public static double factorial(double num){
    if(num == 0) return 1;
    return num * factorial(num -1);
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    int[] radians = {0, 23, 45, 75, 90, 100, 120, 150, 180, 275, 360};
    for (int num : radians) {
        double denom = 0;
        double numrad = num * (2 * Math.PI/360);
        double sum = 0;


        int sign = 1;
        for(int counter = 0; counter < 9; counter++){
            denom = counter * 2 + 1;
            double value = Math.pow(numrad, denom);
            sum += sign * Math.pow(numrad,denom)/factorial(denom);
            sign *= -1;
        }  

        System.out.print(" Angle is: " + num + " = ");
        System.out.printf("%.4f",sum); 
        System.out.println();
      }
    }

}
```

EDIT:

Output:

```
Angle is: 0 = 0.0000  
Angle is: 23 = 0.3907  
Angle is: 45 = 0.7071  
Angle is: 75 = 0.9659  
Angle is: 90 = 1.0000  
Angle is: 100 = 0.9848  
Angle is: 120 = 0.8660  
Angle is: 150 = 0.5000  
Angle is: 180 = 0.0000  
Angle is: 275 = -0.9961  
Angle is: 360 = 0.0110
```

Comment: Oops!My bad... Thanks.

Comment: But I've updated the question. Can you help me answer that?

Comment: Changed the counter to 9 and it is coming close. edited the post.

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much for spotting that. I think the issue is with the  convergence of the Taylor series for large values. Thanks once again.